# verdaccio with private token

Tags: npm, npm-install, verdaccio

I have a private artifactory in my office.
I use verdaccio for download npms from internet and after it in insert them to private artifactory.
It works wonderfool.
I bought Font Awesome pro version , and want to download npm.
How can I pass to verdaccion security token ?
Without token I can't download npm

tnx

Answer (score 4):

You can actually set up a token peer `uplink` which will be included in each request:

With [Verdaccio](https://verdaccio.org) there is 2 ways to achieve what you need:

1. With environment variables

If you want to customize your own environment variable.

```
uplinks:
  private:
    url: https://private-registry.domain.com/registry
    auth:
      type: bearer
      token_env: FOO_TOKEN
```

or us the default `NPM_TOKEN` recognized by verdaccio.

```
uplinks:
  private:
    url: https://private-registry.domain.com/registry
    auth:
      type: bearer
      token_env: true # defaults to `process.env['NPM_TOKEN']`
```

This is handy on CI environments where you are afraid to leak sensitive information.

2. Token in the config file

```
uplinks:
  private:
    url: https://private-registry.domain.com/registry
    auth:
      type: bearer
      token: "token"
```

I'd recommend do this only for local development, in any other case please use option 1.

For more information refer to the [official documentation about uplinks](https://verdaccio.org/docs/en/uplinks).

Remember you can have different uplinks that refers to the same registry, eg:

```
uplinks:
  private:
    url: https://private-registry.domain.com/registry
    auth:
      type: bearer
      token: "token"  
   private2:
    url: https://private-registry.domain.com/registry2
    auth:
      type: bearer
      token: "token"

 packages:
   '@my-company/*':
     access: $access
     publish: $authenticated
     proxy: private private2
```

In this scenario, the package would have access to two sources protected by token, if one return 404 the second proxy will try to resolve your request.